# How can I use 's///' if my string contains a '/'?

Tags: perl

I'm using Perl 5.10.6 on Mac 10.6.6.  I want to execute a simple search and replace against a file so I tried:

```
my $searchAndReplaceCmd = "perl -pi -e 's/\\Q${localTestDir}\\E//g' ${testSuiteFile}";
system( $searchAndReplaceCmd );
```

but the problem above is the variable `$localTestDir` contains directory separators (`"/"`), and this screws up the regular expression ...

> Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near
>   "s/\Q/home/selenium"
>
> Backslash found where operator expected at -e
>   line 1, near "Live\" syntax error at -e line 1, near
>   "s/\Q/home/selenium"
>
> Search pattern not terminated at -e line 1.

How do I do a search and replace on a file when the variable in question contains regular expression characters?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question is why you do a search and replace from within perl, through the shell, within perl. Seems like a roundabout way of doing things, and you'll run into problems with shell interpolation.

The `\Q ... \E` should override the special characters in your string, so `/` "should" not be an issue. From [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html):

```
\Q          quote (disable) pattern metacharacters till \E
```

Here's an alternative (untested), all perl solution. If you want to be extra certain, exchange the `/` delimiter to something else, such as `s###` (you can use any character as a delimiter).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Copy;

open my $fh, '<', $testSuiteFile or die $!;
open my $out, '>', $testSuiteFile . ".bak" or die $!;

while (<$fh>) {
    s/\Q${localTestDir}\E//g;
    print $out $_;
}

move($testSuiteFile . ".bak", $testSuiteFile) or die $!;
```

Or use [Tie::File](http://search.cpan.org/~mjd/Tie-File-0.96/lib/Tie/File.pm)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tie::File;

tie, my @file, 'Tie::File', $testSuiteFile or die $!;

for (@file) {
        s/\Q${localTestDir}\E//g;
}
untie @file;
```

Comment: @Dave Perl is very lovable ;) system calls can be handy, but it is almost always preferable to use pure perl IMO.

Answer (score 6):

It seems that `$localTestDir` has begins with a `/`.

Remedy by changing the regex delimiter to something other than `/`:

```
my $searchAndReplaceCmd = "perl -pi -e 's!\\Q${localTestDir}\\E!!g' ${testSuiteFile}";
```

---

From [`perldoc perlrequick`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html#Search-and-replace) :

> ```
> $x = "A 39% hit rate";
> $x =~ s!(\d+)%!$1/100!e;       # $x contains "A 0.39 hit rate"
> ```
>
> The last example shows that `s///` can use other delimiters, such as
>   `s!!!` and `s{}{}`, and even `s{}//`. If single quotes are used `s'''`, then
>   the regex and replacement are treated as single-quoted strings.

Comment: but what if `$localTestDir` contains a `!`?

Comment: @user5402 : Look at the example in `perlrequick`, use another delimiter: `s###`, `s,,,`, `s<><>`, `s{}//`, etc.

Comment: my point is that you have to choose a delimiter before you know what `$localTestDir` is. What if `$localTestDir` contains all ASCII characters? Now what do you do?

Comment: @user5402 : Put a backslash, as in [Bill Ruppert's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6898808/how-can-i-use-s-if-my-string-contains-a/6899168#6899168)

Comment: Of course, there's also the `quotemeta` option in [TLP's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6898808/how-can-i-use-s-if-my-string-contains-a/6900721#6900721)

Comment: my real point is that the interpolation of `$localTestDir` is happening at the wrong time. See my answer elsewhere for how to safely pass in the value of `$localTestDir` via `system()` to a perl sub-process.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the delimiters is useful, but more generally you can put a backslash in front of any regular expression character to make it non-special.

So s/\/abc/\/xyz/ will work, although it is not very readable.

Comment: aka 'leaning-toothpick-syndrome' :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the substitution of `$localTestDir` is happening too soon.

Here is an approach that lets you use `/` for your re-delimiters:

```
system('perl', '-pi',
       '-e', 'BEGIN { $dir = shift(@ARGV) };',
       '-e', 's/\\Q$dir\\E//g',
       $localTestDir,
       $suiteTestFile
);
```

Note that this also protects the contents of `$suiteTestFile` from being interpreted by the shell.